# Custom jdbc driver for jdbc-source-XXX application

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying  to use MS SQL driver with jdbc app with local data flow server

`jdbc --url='jdbc:sqlserver://server' --driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`

As expected, the driver is not in classpath and I get 
`Cannot load driver class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` when deploying the stream.

I also tried to invoke the data flow server with -cp argument:

`java -cp "C:\path\to\msjdbc.jar " -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar` - same result.

Can anyone help to resolve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions Ilayaperumal Gopinathan, it helped me to resolve the issue.
Looks like the usage of `app.jdbc.spring.cloud.deployer.local.classpath` and `app.jdbc.spring.cloud.deployer.local.main` is undocumented feature and it didn't work for me (at lest with 1.0.1.Release)

I've managed to patch the pre-built jdbc starter and include MS jdbc driver following the documentation from http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_patching_pre_built_applications.

It didn't work with 1.0.1.Release due to this bug (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/748) that was resolved in 1.1.0.Snapshot.

I didn't have to specify any whitelisted properties and 1.1.0.Snapshot picked them up properly from inner jar.

Comment: Thanks Alexander for trying out and the inputs. These features have just been added and we will take care of documentation as early as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The `local` dataflow server spawns the app in a separate process and doesn't use the classpath resources for the app. Hence, I think you need to add the driver into `jdbc` app path. or, you can try setting the `classpath` local deployer deployment property for the `app` when deploying the stream. When specifying `spring.cloud.deployer.local.classpath` property, the property `spring.cloud.deployer.local.main` also needs to be specified.

stream create a1 --definition "time | jdbc"

stream deploy a1 --properties "app.jdbc.spring.cloud.deployer.local.classpath=/temp/myclasspath,app.jdbc.spring.cloud.deployer.local.main="

Comment: Thanks, it does make sense, what should be the `main` in this case ?

Comment: It is the java main application class of the app. If you are using the out-of-the box `jdbc` sink and `app` has `rabbit` binder, then your `main` class is: `org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.jdbc.sink.rabbit.JdbcSinkRabbitApplication`.

Comment: I've tried what you've suggested, but these deployment properties some how got striped out from `deploymentProperties` map. I've run remote debugger and see that they being passed correctly to the `StreamDeploymentController` , but they disappeared  from `AppDeploymentRequest` when I reached  `AbstractLocalDeployerSupport::buildExecutionCommand` method.

Comment: I also followed the Patching pre-built applications guide from http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_patching_pre_built_applications, but `app info source:ms-jdbc` shows empty table. Please advise

Comment: For `app info source:ms-jdbc` to work you need to specify whitelisted properties. http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/spring-cloud-dataflow-register-apps.html#spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-app-whitelisting

Comment: Also, which version of `deployer` are you using? may be the version you are using doesn't support `classpath`. You can try using `1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`.